# What happens when you undelete an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I didn't have enough reputation to comment on the question so I added a comment as an answer with a note:

> I cannot add comment due to less reputation so I am answering it on answer section

A moderator deleted my comment (answer actually), yet I still get the option to undelete it!

What happens if I undelete an answer that has been deleted by moderators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot undelete posts deleted by diamond (♦) moderators.

However it seems you are referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551961/how-can-i-make-a-quote-element-to-be-positioned-at-the-margins-of-a-text-element/62552394#62552394), which was deleted by three other users. You can undelete this post, but it will trigger an automatic flag for diamond moderators to look at, since it was deleted [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26499825) and later undeleted.

As your post is *still* not an answer, it would be deleted by a diamond (♦) moderator again.

I strongly suggest you avoid posting in the answer box unless you can provide a complete answer, otherwise you may hit an [answer ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: It was deleted by 4 users. What did you mean by 3 other users?

Comment: Oops I can't count

Answer (score 3):

For a regular user it is not possible to undelete a comment - so nothing going to happen (and there is no UI elements to do so anyway).

If moderator (one with diamonds) undeletes a comment it just comes back as if the comment was never deleted.

If you posted *not an answer* (i.e. clarification request/recommendation about the question) as an answer and try to undelete it:

- if deleted by a moderator you will not be able to undelete it
- otherwise it will be undeleted, likely downvoted as "not useful as an answer" and flagged again. Most likely leading to loss of ability to post answers due to answer ban.